# I am getting this error "local variable 'col' referenced before assignment" when running the following code:

Tags: python

```
def log_hist(data):
    data = pd.DataFrame([])
    for col in data:
        data_log = np.log(data[col])
    return data[col].hist()




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-dc391683ef40> in <module>()
----> 1 log_hist(df2)

<ipython-input-126-60d8684e3abe> in log_hist(data)
      3     for col in data:
      4         data_log = np.log(data[col])
----> 5     return data[col].hist()
      6 
      7 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'col' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Which value of `col` do you want to use in that last line (the `return`)?  There are many values of `col` but you can only return one of them with that syntax.  (Do you want to return a list of all the `data_log` values?  That's easily done with a list comprehension.)

Comment: Try not to use the iteration variable (`col`) outside of the loop.

Comment: @Klaus. Python actually makes the iteration variable available in the surrounding scope after a for loop (but not for list/dict/generator comprehensions). So it is valid to examine an iteration variable after a for loop (assuming the for loop iterated through something that was non-empty). In some cases you might want to do this if you called break in the middle of the loop for example. You perhaps already know all this.

Comment: @MattMiguel I very aware of that. And I'm also aware of the fact that it fails if the sequence you are iterating over is empty. So, you need an extra control structure to make sure that what you describe works.

Comment: @KlausD. ok nevermind then, sorry. :)

Comment: @Samwise  I want to use any data frame  and log transform every columns in the data, then use histogram for each column in the data

Comment: @DinaD which of those histograms do you want to `return`, though?  The first one?  The last one?  All of them?

Comment: @Samwise the last one

Answer (score 1):

Since your dataframe is empty, there is nothing to iterate through. The for loop does not instantiate the col variable. If your iterable (the dataframe) was not empty, then the variable would be available after the loop.

Example of idea:

```py
>>> for x in range(10):
...  pass
... 
>>> x
9
>>> for y in []:
...  pass
... 
>>> y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `col` is only valid within the `for` loop.  If you want to access the value outside of the loop (e.g. to capture the last value that is processed by the loop), declare a variable outside of the loop:

```
def log_hist(data):
    last_col = None
    for col in data:
        np.log(data[col])
        last_col = col
    return data[last_col].hist()  # will raise an exception if the dataframe is empty!
```

Note that I removed the line at the start of your function which zeroes out the `data` parameter -- I assume this was part of some debugging attempt, but it obviously completely breaks the function to have that in there.  :)

I also removed the `data_log` variable since it's not used anywhere; there's no point assigning a variable that you never use.  (I'm not familiar with `np.log`, I assume it has a side-effect that is desirable -- otherwise the loop is mostly pointless to begin with and should be replaced with code that simply selects the last column without looping through the entire object.)